# What is the right way to store an object's graphical informations ?

Tags: java, oop

I'm quite new to OOP/Design Patterns and I'm dealing with a design issue when it comes to separating the logical informations of my objects from their graphical status :

In the Java the musical application I'm trying to make I have a **Chord** class which is composed of either **Note** classes or **Rest** classes.

In these classes I store "logical" informations such as the midi value of a note, its velocity, etc.

I want to draw these chords on a **Staff** object (that extends some kind of GUI **Panel** object) : to do such thing I need to add some informations to my classes, such as the position of my objects on the staff or their symbol.

So, I made graphical "equivalent" of my classes, holding these graphical informations, as well as encapsulating my logical Chords, as you can see in the following diagram :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4fQ3.png

But I'm stuck with something that I think is really strange : my diagram is mirrored in its center (which make me think my graphical classes are somewhat useless) and I can't really create a **GraphicChord** object from a **Chord** on the fly because I can't know if I should make a **GraphicNote** or a **GraphicRest** for each **SimpleElement** my **Chord** contains...

I'm sure there's something about design principles I must be doing very wrong but I can't find another way to add graphical informations to my objects…

Can you please help me ?

Comment: Why do you need both a GraphicRest and a GraphicNote class?

Comment: @MikkelLøkke I want to store the symbol representing my element inside the GraphicNote and GraphicRest classes. For the same duration a Note and a Rest are not represented with the same symbol (a quarter note is displayed differently than a quarter rest)

Comment: Fair enough. But why do this through separate classes tho'? Why not just make the symbol to use a member (field or property)  of the GraphicSimpleElement, if this essentially constant is the only difference between the two?

As a general rule, given concepts A and B, they can safely be represented by the same class, unless they have different (mutable) states or behavior. In your case, as it is presented here it would be fine to have it as a property, and as Dawnkeeper suggests, this can be inferred from the type of your SimpleElement.

Comment: They are drawn differently (of course) but then you'd to have a 'sharp' class and a flat class, and a tempo class, and a dot class, and a quarter, half, full, eight, trill, etc class too AND a GUI version of each. The GUI is an object itself, using the data from the note/chord classes to draw them! I'm no expert here, so take it with a grain of salt, but I think (and this has happened me in other arenas) your musical knowledge is actually getting in the way of your programming here! rossGUI.draw(rossChord);  rossGUI.draw(rossQuarterRest); etc.

Comment: Okay I now get what you are both saying. It appears that I don't need to have two different classes for my simplest graphical elements, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working with 2 different groups of related objects. You are doing it right in your diagram, having the basic idea, but, needs some "cleanup".

As you already notest, one group is composed by the objects that store the data or model. A song object may be composed, by several notes.

The other group, represents the visual or graphical representation of the data or model. You may display a music pentagram, that has several sections, and the notes of the same song & rests, are displayed visually.

You may use the "Decorator Software Design Pattern":

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

```
But I'm stuck with something that I think is really strange :
my diagram is mirrored in its center
(which make me think my graphical classes are somewhat useless)
and I can't really create a GraphicChord object from a Chord
on the fly because I can't know if I should make a
GraphicNote or a GraphicRest for each SimpleElement my Chord contains...
```

In this case of problem, it's OK, that many classes are duplicated or "mirrored", since a group represent the model, and, another group, the visual representation of the same model.

Do not get surprised, if other people say you are wrong, because you have a duplicate of the classes. In this special case of scenario, the duplication of information, is right.

Now, about your question, think like a non programming user. A non programming user, doesn't think about the data or model classes. He / She, thinks about the Interface / GUI classes, and, works with them.

When the user (or you) create a chord, then, he / she really creates a GraphicalChord, and, the GraphicalChord, will create an internal Chord, behind the scenes. The user adds a Note or Rest, and, really adds, a Graphical Note, or, a Graphical Rest, and, those objects, will create a Data Note, or Data Rest, and, added to the Chord.

I suggest to add a prefix or suffix to you non graphical classes, like "RealChord", "DataChord", or alike, in order to avoid confusion with the GUI Classes.

In the case of "SimpleElement" since, it's already known that it will have 2 subclasses, you may add a enumerated property to know which class, it is.

```
public enum ElementTypeEnum {
    UNASSIGNED,
    NOTE,
    REST
}

public class SimpleElementClass {
  private ElementTypeEnum _ElementType;

 public void setElementType(ElementTypeEnum n){
    _ElementType = n;
  }
  public ElementTypeEnum getElementType(){
    return _ElementType;
  }

  /* other members */
} // class SimpleElementClass

public class NoteClass extends SimpleElementClass { 
  /* other members */
} // class NoteClass

public class RestClass extends SimpleElementClass { 
  /* other members */
} // class RestClass
```

This way, when you add any object that implement the subclasses, you can quickly infer, which type is it. The Chord classes, works at some level with the "SimpleElementClass" class, instead of the subclasses.

Cheers

Comment: Thank's a lot for your suggestion! I was kind of seeing the issue the other way around (I thought about creating GraphicChord from a Chord instead of doing the opposite)

Answer (score 0):

> I can't really create a GraphicChord object from a Chord on the fly because I can't know if I should make a GraphicNote or a GraphicRest for each SimpleElement my Chord contains

If that is the only reason for having the Graphic objects you can use `instanceof` to check what kind of SimpleElement you have.

```
if(myCurrentSimpleObject instanceof Note)
{
   // create Graphic object on the fly
}
```

---

If you want to avoid using `instanceof` you could change your SimpleElement class by adding an abstract method to determine the object type.

```
 abstract boolean isNote();
```

The child classes would have to implement this method and return a fixed true or false.
This can be scaled to multiple classes by returning an enumeration value that describes the class.

If your child classes have methods specific to them, you will still have to cast them to the correct class. And if you want to avoid 'unchecked class cast' compiler warnings while doing this you are still stuck with `instanceof`

Comment: I thought about that, but isn't instanceof something to avoid, generally speaking?

Comment: It wouldn't be there if it didn't have its uses. But this gave me an idea. Will update the answer.

Comment: I hear that a lot about generally avoiding instanceof, and don't have the faintest idea where it comes from or why, people think it's a bad idea. In any case, you can use reflection (getClass().isAssignableFrom()) instead.

Comment: Thank's. That's indeed a great way to check the type of my elements. I was told not to use instanceof because this suggest that we're programming to a instance rather than to an interface.